# jQuery switch not setting default icon but showing both

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this switch which when clicked will change the next hidden value to 0 or 1 but I need it to set the right icon based on the value on load but cannot work it out.

```js
// Enable / Disable feature columns
$('[id^=PC_Row]').each(function() {
  var $featureStatuses = $(this);
  if ($featureStatuses == "1") {
    $featureStatuses.prev('.inactive').hide();
  } else {
    $featureStatuses.prev('.active').hide();
  }
});

$('.switch').click(function() {
  $(this).find('.inactive, .active').toggle();
  var featureStatus = $(this).find('[id^=PC_Row]').val();
  //console.log(featureStatus);
  if (featureStatus == "1") {
    $(this).find('[id^=PC_Row]').val('0');
  } else {
    $(this).find('[id^=PC_Row]').val('1');
  }

});
```

```css
    .switch-wrapper {
      text-align: center;
    }
    .switch {
      font-size: 1.5em;
      margin: 0 auto;
      position: relative;
      height: 50px;
      width: 25px;
    }
    .switch i {
      position: absolute;
      top: 14px;
      left: 0;
    }
    .switch .active {
      color: green;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">

<div class="switch-wrapper">
  <div class="switch">
    <i class="fa fa-toggle-on active"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-rotate-180 inactive"></i>
    <input type="hidden" id="PC_Row_1_Feature_1_Enabled" name="PC_Row_1_Feature_1_Enabled" value="1">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="switch-wrapper">
  <div class="switch">
    <i class="fa fa-toggle-on active"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-rotate-180 inactive"></i>
    <input type="hidden" id="PC_Row_1_Feature_1_Enabled" name="PC_Row_1_Feature_1_Enabled" value="1">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="switch-wrapper">
  <div class="switch">
    <i class="fa fa-toggle-on active"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-rotate-180 inactive"></i>
    <input type="hidden" id="PC_Row_1_Feature_1_Enabled" name="PC_Row_1_Feature_1_Enabled" value="0">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="switch-wrapper">
  <div class="switch">
    <i class="fa fa-toggle-on active"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-rotate-180 inactive"></i>
    <input type="hidden" id="PC_Row_1_Feature_1_Enabled" name="PC_Row_1_Feature_1_Enabled" value="0">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: May I suggest you a better solution without `JavaScript` at all?

Comment: Sure, i have a lot of PHP controlling stuff but by all means please suggest, reason used JS and was better supported cross browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you could simplify your code, something like this on Javascript code:

```
    $('.switch').click(function(){
      var i = $(this).find('i');

      i.toggleClass('fa-rotate-180');

      $(this).find('input[type=hidden]').val(i.hasClass('fa-rotate-180')?'1':'0');
    });
```

And for HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="switch">
  <i class="fa fa-toggle-on active"></i>
  <input type="hidden" name="name" value="0">
</a>
```

This is general way to do but maybe this could help you for what you want

Comment: How would it set inactive class as thats what changes colour? ill give it a try in a second.

Comment: Switches fine so cool on that, anyway to toggle the active and inactive depending on status 1 or 0 like rotate?

Comment: Oh right, I missing that jeje. You could add more class to toggleClass function in order, something like this: i.toggleClass('active fa-rotate-180 inactive');

Comment: Not depending on status, It is depending on classes

Comment: Thanks for your help on this!

Comment: Don't worry jeje, Please let me know if you need something else about this, have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

```css
.switch-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}
.switch {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 25px;
}
.switch i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 14px;
  left: 0;
}
.switch .active {
  color: green;
}

input {
  display:none;
}

input:not(:checked) ~ .active,
input:checked ~ .inactive {
  display:none;  
}

input:checked ~ .inactive,
input:not(:checked) ~ .active {
  display:none;  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">

<div class="switch-wrapper">
  <div class="switch">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="PC_Row_1_Feature_1_Enabled" checked="checked" value="1" />
      <i class="fa fa-toggle-on active"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-rotate-180 inactive"></i>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="switch-wrapper">
  <div class="switch">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="PC_Row_1_Feature_1_Enabled" value="0" />
      <i class="fa fa-toggle-on active"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-rotate-180 inactive"></i>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="switch-wrapper">
  <div class="switch">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="PC_Row_1_Feature_1_Enabled" checked="checked" value="1" />
      <i class="fa fa-toggle-on active"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-rotate-180 inactive"></i>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="switch-wrapper">
  <div class="switch">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="PC_Row_1_Feature_1_Enabled" value="0" />
      <i class="fa fa-toggle-on active"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-rotate-180 inactive"></i>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```